# Validation in PHP not being understood

Tags: php, validation

I am having difficulty understanding the PHP code below.

The first line of the code is a superglobal variable with a request element in it:
I assume this line simply states which method was used to send data to the server, in this case POST was used.

But what I am a little fuzzy about is the second line.
Do I understand correctly that this line means "*if no name is posted, then something happens*"?
That *something* seems to be the third line, or else the fourth line is activated.
This is where I get lost.

The third line assigns a statement to the variable `$error`, and the fourth line assigns another statement to the variable `$name`.
But `$error` seems to have TWO different statements attached to it, and I am not clear as to what `$name = test_input($_POST["name"])` means.
In other words, only line number one is clear to me, and the line containing "*if NOT preg match*", because I'm familiar with preg match.

BUT, what I am also not clear about is the line that comes after "if NOT preg match".
Does `$name = ""` mean that if you input anything other than letters or whitespace, then what you have just typed in will be deleted?

And (again) I am confused about the fact that `$error` has **two** values associated with it.
Could someone please enlighten me?

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $error = "Name is required";
    } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);

        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
            $name = "";
            $error = "Anything that is not letters or whitespace are not allowed";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code comes from  W3Schools articles. I recommend you to read all of them. They are very detailed.

1. [PHP 5 Form Handling](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)
2. [PHP 5 Form Validation](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp)
3. [PHP 5 Forms - Required Fields](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_required.asp) (*your code is here*)
4. [PHP 5 Forms - Validate E-mail and URL](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_url_email.asp) (*and here*)
5. [PHP 5 Complete Form Example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp)

Read these articles, they have pretty good explanations.

`$error` is assigned only once, since one is on the `if` and the other is on the `else`. [This](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.if.php) may also help you.

Comment: OK,understood, and thanks for pointing me out to the websites.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code (just indenting wise) to make it easier for you to read. Start indenting your code that way and you won't get as confused:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{
   if (empty($_POST["name"])) 
   {
      $error = "Name is required";
   }
   else
   {
      $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
      if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) 
      {
         $name = "";
         $error = "Anything that is not letters or whitespace are not allowed";
      }
   }
   ...
}
```

`{` opens a block, `}` closes it. If you know what `if` and `else` mean it should be obvious now. If not, go read the PHP manual on [Control Structures](https://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php).

But it should be obvious, code inside an `if` block is only run when the condition is true.  Code in the `else` block is run if the condition of the preceding `if` was not true.   So `$error` does not have two values.  Its value depends on the values of the checks in the if-statements.

Comment: Yes, I understand it better with your indentation. Thanks kindly.